# Can we show off questions in the developer story?

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

Reasoning:

It shows that we crave knowledge and are able to work as a "team" with the community to solve our questions.

**Note**: this is not about top questions. This is about the questions you're proud of. Just like some top voted questions are caused by fgitw, some top answers are as well. I think answers should also be selected by the user; not the highest voted ones.

Comment: Because most people want to show off their knowledge via their answers, I'd expect?

Comment: @Oded I added some good reasoning :-)

Comment: @Oded if you participate in language-lawyer-ing or some of the other more meta tags, the questions can be just as impressive (/tedious, if you prefer ;) ) as the answers.

Comment: @Neal that's semantically the biggest edit I've ever seen on any SO site. The ability to ask good questions (and the right questions) is important. It showcases how I learn new things. If you hire me, you can have some assurance that I at least know how to ask good questions, and do my own research before.

Comment: @FilipHaglund If you disagree with my edit you can change it if you want. I just thought that it made a better question this way instead of a pseudo complaint :-)

Comment: I actually think we're talking about different things here. I want to be able to select questions I'm proud of, which avoids the first questioneer in the west problem of just showing the top questions. The top answers should have this same problem; first question/answer on new feature in a popular tag -> tons of rep. Those are not the things I want to show off.

Comment: Such strong opinions in regards to what **other** people want to do with their Dev Story! Hilarious

Comment: How is this a duplicate of that? At all?

Comment: I removed the [status-review] tag from this post because the Jobs product no longer exists.

Answer (score 10):

I completely agree that users should be able to add questions to their CVs/Stories. I was slightly surprised to learn here that it wasn't possible.

A truly good question displays positive (employment) attributes as much as a good answer does. It shows your ability to communicate the nature of a problem to your peers. It has to be clear, and walk a fine line of providing sufficient information without diving into excruciating detail. Your thought process and your ability to research a problem are laid out. It also shows that you're willing to ask for help if you're stuck: a component of teamwork. These are all traits that you may want to highlight for potential employers.

These things may not be covered just in your "top" questions: as others have pointed out, sometimes a high score just means you got there first (my own top answer is one of these: I don't want it anywhere near my resume). A link to any of your Stack Overflow questions should be allowed, as it is for answers. Any post that you're proud of and want to show off should be fair game.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with this.

It allows people to show off that they learned something.

For me (for example) I learned *a ton* from [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/561731), and many other people did as well and I might want to show that off somewhere.

Answer (score -3):

I disagree with this. If you look at many high rep users, you'll see a trait of many questions asked such as:

"What does this do in JS/Python/C#/etc?"

Where the question was asked after a feature came out, and is typically answered in the docs. It only has so many votes because it was the first to have been asked. Doesn't mean it's a good question to show off in my opinion.

Comment: This problem also applies to answers. I want to post qurstions (and answers) I'm proud of; not the top rated ones.